# Drush command not recognized after installing globally via Composer

Tags: bash, path, drush

I recently installed Composer globally on my system (following instructions found on getcomposer.org). After that, I attempted to install Drush via composer. As the first step in the Drush install, I added composer's bin directory to my system path.

So, in my .bash_profile I added the following:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

After that, I installed the latest version of Drush with the following command:

```
composer global require drush/drush
```

Unfortunately, every time I try to type 'drush status', I get a 'drush not found' error message in my prompt. I've tried to uninstall/reinstall both composer and Drush, with no effect.

All the research I've done on this issue leads to threads that involve updating the system path, but I'm pretty sure I've done this step correctly. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here because this should be a fairly simple process. Any ideas where I might be going wrong?

Comment: Did you restart your shell session after adding the `PATH` line to your `.bash_profile` script? Does the output from `tr : \\n <<<"$PATH"` contain the path you added?

Comment: Etan, thank you for the quick response. I did restart the shell session and the output shows that path I added. I must be forgetting something very basic, just can't seem to figure it out. Thanks again for responding so quickly

Comment: And is `drush` in `$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin`? Is it executable? What does `head -n 1 $HOME/.composer/vendor/bin/drush` say?

Comment: I've confirmed that drush is in the directory you listed in your previous message. Here is the output from the 'head -n 1...' command:  #!/usr/bin/env sh

Comment: And what is the *exact* error you get when you try to run `drush`? And does running `$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin/drush status` work correctly?

Comment: Here is the exact error: zsh: command not found: drush                                       Running the full path works correctly too. Thanks again for looking into this, I've been playing around with it tonight and it's driving me a little crazy.

Comment: In a new shell session what do `cat -vET <<<"$PATH"` and `type -a drush` output?

Comment: So I finally worked it out. Essentially, I was updating my $PATH in the wrong place. I kept tweaking things in my .bash_profile when I should have really been focused on my .zshrc. The reason it was failing in my .zshrc is because I was using a '~' instead of the $HOME variable. Sorry for the trouble but I really appreciate you helping me troubleshoot. The long and short of it is I don't really know what I'm doing and am new to the field, but it's been a great introduction to the command line that's for sure.

Comment: That sounds like an answer worth adding to me. I'd suggest writing that up and accepting it. Either that or deleting the question if you don't think it'll be of use to anyone else as written.

Comment: Thanks Etan, is there any way I can give you credit? The only reason I 'found' the fix was due to your diagnosis. I haven't used stackoverflow very much so I'm not sure how the etiquette works. Just want to make sure I give credit where credit is due.

Comment: If you write up the answer yourself then officially, no. That said you can very easily include that information in the actual content of the answer (by way of explaining how you got to your solution). I'm fine with that.

Answer (score 3):

Drush wasn't working globally because I was not updating the correct $PATH. I was adding it to my .bash_profile when I should have been updating .zshrc. Thanks to Etan Reisner I was able to identify the problem and find the solution.

In the future when looking at $PATH variables, I should probably type this in my terminal to make sure I'm looking in the right place:

```
$ which $SHELL
```